# Microsoft Excel 2010 formula

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I have this formula:

```
=AVERAGEIFS('MASTER DATA SHEET'!$I:$I,'MASTER DATA SHEET'!$A:$A,"july",'MASTER DATA SHEET'!$B:$B,"Industrial",'MASTER DATA SHEET'!$I:$I,">0")/4
```

No interviews were done in July, and it is therefore giving me a Div0 error.  I cannot get the part right to make the cell a 0 or a blank.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a data sample and the expected result it is hard to suggest a formula that you may find usable.

If you want to avoid the error message, you can wrap the formula in an IfError statement, like this:

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS('MASTER DATA SHEET'!$I:$I,'MASTER DATA SHEET'!$A:$A,"july",'MASTER DATA SHEET'!$B:$B,"Industrial",'MASTER DATA SHEET'!$I:$I,">0")/4,"")
```

If the AverageIfs throws an error, the result of the formula will be an empty string.